# Доступ в каталогах Linux

Tags: linux, chmod

Как сделать, чтобы в заблокированном для других пользователей домашнем каталоге, один из подкаталогов (`docs`) был бы доступным другим пользователям?

Пробовал с помощью `chmod` ставить подкаталогу статус 755, но это ничего не давало.
Спасибо.

Comment: Чтобы подкаталог был доступен, родительский каталог тоже должен быть доступен

Comment: сделайте на него ссылку с помощью `ln` из `/opt` например, но всё это должно быть в одной файловой системе (на одном разделе диска), эта ссылка может иметь любые права и владельцев, это не касается символических ссылок